# Using priors to detect an effect? logistic Bayesian regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, bayesian, bayes

I have designed an idea and am looking for similar approaches in other literature/areas or if I have applied the Bayesian concepts wrongly. Here is a statement of my problem:

1. I am modeling the influence of a single variable X on the odds of a death event. The base chance is 15%.
2. I am going to take the approach of using log(p/1-p)=alpha+beta*x to model the odds ( Logistic regression ).
3. I measure X in terms of 1 unit increases, so 1 increase in X will typically increase the chances of death by an additive amount. ( 1 increase in X -> +5% more risk, or +10% or +20% Note we do have 1.5,1.9.. but I was just getting across the idea of the effect of X).
4. I only have 17 data points relating X and death. That's not enough given my power analysis.
5. I construct 4 sets of priors, not based on the data, just based on an agreeable reasonable effect between the scientist and myself. I'm lacking literature here, but the researchers do feel comfortable about my approach. The first prior (normal) assumes a base chance of 15%, and an increasing additive effect of X around 5%, the second assumes a base chance of 15% and an additive effect of increasing X around 10%. ( Normal priors with certain standard deviations control the "around" part ). etc.
6. Run the bayes analysis using data I have and the 4 separate priors. It may be that one posterior based on a prior 5% effect tells me the effect is likely higher. While the 15% effect posterior tells me the effect is likely lower. I realize I may possibly get conflicting information.
7. From this I believe that the effect is somewhere between 5% and 15% and on another new sampled dataset, repeat this with the priors being near those ranges to narrow it down.
8. I can specifically quantify the judgement I used in 6, by estimating the posterior probability that the effect is more than 5%, etc.

Any thoughts, criticisms? 
I think this approach is valid. I realize the effect of the X variable could be different ( ie not additive ).

Thank you.

Comment: I've researched the idea further and have found that the priors should incorporate a true known effect if they are to be informative. In other words they should be based on some past experiment, or pilot study which lends credence to their assumption. Otherwise I could use a community of priors with them being centered at a null effect of 0%.